# Why is bundler looking for mysql2 -v '0.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Below is my Gemfile but i haven't specified the mysql2 version but for some reason it's looking for 0.4.4. It must be a dependency of another gem. I was just assigned thAny ideas?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc5'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'acts_as_better_tree'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.8'
gem 'apipie-rails', :github => 'Apipie/apipie-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'petergate'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'authorizenet'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.3.2'
gem 'roo-xls', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.5'
gem 'html5shiv-rails'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf_binary'


gem "minitest-rails"
gem "minitest-reporters"
gem 'airbrake', '~> 5.6'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Comment: Which version do you want it to look for?

Comment: I don't have no direction from management, so the newest one I guess. I would expect bundler to pull the latest because the version isn't specified.

Comment: When I run bundle install I get this error:
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

When I run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` in a new shell I get:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (= 0.4.4) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/...

Comment: So if version 0.4.4 doesn't exist what gem requires it?

Comment: You can try `bundle install --verbose` to see the details.

Comment: I don't know what the answer to this question is but I just changed my Gemfile to read `gem 'mysql2', '> 0.4.4', group: :production` and it bundled just fine. My guess is that there is something wrong with one of the compile files.

Answer (score 1):

`$ gem dependency mysql2 --reverse-dependencies`

It'll list each version of `mysql2` and then the gems that depend on that version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the rails version and mysql2 version. Change the Gemfile line that contains `gem 'mysql2'` to `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.0'`

I have `gem 'rails', '4.2.6'` installed but apparently there is some compile error with mysql2 and that version of rails.

"For Rails 4.x please pin the gem to mysql2 '~> 0.4.0'" - [sodabrew](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/950#issuecomment-376259151)

After doing this the `bundle install` ran and I was able to run `rails c` without errors.